# Customized Regex Code with Character

Tags: c#, regex

Goal:
The first letter shall be a small or a big character only and after that, the data ":\\" is should follow along.  Data ":\\" is static.

Problem:
I have problem with my regex code.

```
^[a-zA-Z]:*$
```

Info:

```
C:\\dd\\sd\\faf.txt      true
c:\\ss\\dw\\fbf.txt      true
D:\\ff\\d3\\fcf.txt      true
d:\\da\\ds\\Df\\ff.txt   true
2:\\ad\\dd\\ff           false
2:\ad\\dd\\ff            false
d:\da\\ds\\Df\\ff.txt    false
c\\ss\\dw\\fbf.txt       false
D:\da\\ds\\Df\\ff.txt    false
```

Comment: Do your strings really contain double backslashes, or is that just how they look in your string literals?  Are you aware that you can use C# *verbatim string* literals to avoid all that double-backslash hassle?  For example, `var myString = @"C:\dd\sd\faf.txt";` creates the exact string `C:\dd\sd\faf.txt`

Comment: I'm aware about it. Due to syntax code HttpPostedFileBase from asp.net mvc you retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) can do for you:

[image]

Comment: It is almost correft that is "^[a-zA-Z]:\\*" as a answer. More complementory will come.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect correct PATH format in Windows.
Using this pattern can help: `^[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\[^\\]+)*`
You can check [my sample](https://regex101.com/r/mV0hT1/2). Also note I add one more test to it:

```
D:\\da\\ds\Df\\ff.txt    false
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your missing a .*  after the : Below should work.

```
^[a-zA-Z]:.*$
```