# Complemetory in a Customized Regex Code

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

Goal:
Make sure that the data1 and all the way to data31 is correct and data4 and all the way to data7 is error with support of regex

```
 Regex regexp = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\.*$");
```

in C#.

Problem:
data6 and data7 is supposed to be error but instead it is correct.

Don't know how to solve it.

```
    Regex regexp = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\.*$");

    //Correct result
    string data1 = "C:\\33\\dd\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data2 = "c:\\ff\\ded\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data3 = "Z:\\ss\\gg\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data31 = "d:\\da\\ds\\Df\\ff.txt";

    //Error result
    string data4 = "3:\\rr\\555\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data5 = "d\\33\\4\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data6 = "s:\\\\rr\\d\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";
    string data7 = "s:\\\\\\f\\f\\Desktop\\151222055438.txt";


    if (regexp.Match(data1).Success)
    {
        int correct = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data2).Success)
    {
        int correct = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data3).Success)
    {
        int correct = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data31).Success)
    {
        int correct = 23;
    }



    if (regexp.Match(data4).Success)
    {
        int error = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data5).Success)
    {
        int error = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data6).Success)
    {
        int error = 23;
    }

    if (regexp.Match(data7).Success)
    {
        int error = 23;
    }

    int sds = 23;
```

Comment: It looks like you are validating filenames, why not use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-sharp-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved in an [answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500912/20938).  You just have to adapt it to work with single instead of double backslashes:

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:(\\[^\\]+)+$");
```

`\\` matches a single backslash (because `\` is not special in a verbatim string literal, but it is special in a regex). Then `[^\\]+` matches one or more of any characters *except* backslash; that's the directory or file name.

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight modification to your expression so that it becomes as follows: `^[a-zA-Z]:(\\{2}[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)+$` (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/xH6nG3/1)).

In your case, you seem to be looking explicitly for pairs of `\` characters, which is what the `\\{2}` does. Also, between the pairs of `\` you seem to only be accepting letters and numbers. At the end, you seem to be also looking for period characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Regex regexp = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:(\\{2}[a-zA-Z\d]+)+(\\{2}[\d]+)*.txt$");
```

IF your files have `".txt"` extension and have only digits in name, this might work even better.

The reason for two slashes `"\\"` is to indicate backslash. as it will consider single backslash as escape character.